# Evenly Distribute Players between 2 teams in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a group of players, 915 in total, each with different engagement scores that I am trying to break out into two evenly distributed groups based on their engagement scores. I tried using Solver in excel to set contstraints, indices etc, but unfortunately Solver can only handle 200 variables, and I have 915. Another approach I researched is to give the first group with the best player also the worst player, give the second group the second best player and the second worst player, and so on. Problem is I am not an excel wiz and need some help writing out this formula in excel so both columns A and B show "1's" for the agents that should be selected for both groups in the group A and group B columns in the below screenshot (the screenshot is a small sample of the entire data set, FYI),
[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgrvo.jpg)

Comment: Contact Frontline - they have a more powerful solver available than the standard one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned combination of best and worst player.

Your data is already sorted on descending index. Say, the data is in A,B and C Columns. Just put A in D2 and B in D3.

Select D2 and D3 and once you get + cursor on the bottom right of the selection, double click.

Filter A for group A  and B for group B.